# Conditions are only met in first iteration

Tags: python

Solved so remedied code below to help anyone if they stumble upon this...
Original issue - Only inputs other than integers filtered out, and not integers outside of the range 1-10.

```
    lc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #string for lc
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

while True:
    try:
        passlen = int(input("How many lower case characters would you like in the password? (min 1, max 10) "))
        if 1<= passlen<=10:
                    a =  "".join(random.sample(lc,passlen))
                    print("")


                    counter = counter + (passlen)
                    left = 10 - counter
                    nleft = 16 - counter
                    if counter < 10:
                        print("You have used", counter, "characters. You need a minimum of", left, "characters and a maxium of", nleft, "characters to create a password of between 10 and 16 charcters.")
                        print("")

                    elif counter > 16:
                        print("You have used", counter, "charcters, more than the allowed maximum of 16 characters. Please follow the rest of the steps and retry when prompted.")

                    else:
                        print("You have used", counter, "characters, so have met the minimum amount of characters. You have a maximum of", nleft, "characters remaining to create a password with maximum 16 characters.")
                        print("")

                    break

        else:
            print("Input must be an integer between 1 and 10, please try again.")
    except ValueError:
            print("Input type must be an integer.")
```

Comment: It's completely unclear what this code should be doing, plus the problem itself isn't obvious.

Comment: Can you please provide an [mcve] of your problem?

Comment: As a matter of style, "interactive" programs like this died in the 1980s. It's much better to write a command-line tool that takes in arguments over `sys.argv`, like where you'd have a program `python passgen.py 20` which would generate a 20-character password or error out if the argument is omitted or out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you enter a number outside the range 1-10, it skips the `while` loop where you try to handle the error, specifically `while passlen <1 or passlen >10:`.

To fix this, handle this logic inside the first `while` loop and get rid of the second one (omitted long print messages for brevity). E.g.

```
while True:
    try:
        passlen = int(input("How many lower case characters would you like in the password? (min 1, max 10) "))
        if 1 <= pathlen <= 10:
            break
        else:
            print("Input must be an integer between 1 and 10, please try again.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Input type not recognized")
```

Comment: yes. works like a charm, thanks. from here, how do i bring this filtered input outside the while loop (to the code below it)?

Comment: You can put all the code in your last else clause following this.

Comment: yeah, had just worked that out before reading your reply - (feel a bit silly now tbh) re ordered the break so iteration is now altered by input etc. thanks for the help, appreciate it as i'm a beginner...especially as the problem was not very clear (first post etc). anyway program runs perfectly. cheers boss.